# Does any country require a duration longer than 6 months beyond the date of the intended departure for the passport validity when entering the country

Tags: passports

When entering a country, a common requirement is that one's passport must be valid for some time after the entry, e.g. one, three or six months after the entry, or six months beyond the date of the intended departure.

Comment: in what way is this a practical problem that you face?

Comment: @KateGregory knowing if 6 months is always good enough when traveling

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I suggest checking the requirements of your destination before you travel, when you're actually planning to travel there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not useful and is asking for a tidbit trivia.

Comment: @littleadv it is very useful to me and it's not a trivia: I want to use it to know if 6 months is always good enough when traveling. If I know the upper bound then it will save me some time.

Comment: Right, useful to you. Not to anyone else though.

Comment: @littleadv speak for yourself

Comment: Travel trivia are acceptable questions here, by tradition.

Answer (score -3):

https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/which-countries-require-6-months-of-passport-validity surveyed 146 countries and the maximum is 6 months.

---

I'll copy their country list below:

| Country | Visaguide 2001 | US passport Guide | Daily Record 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Albania | 3 months ARV |  |  |
| Algeria | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Angola |  | 6 |  |
| Anguilla | 6 |  | 6 |
| Antigua and Barbuda |  | 6 |  |
| Austria | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Azerbaijan | 3 months DEP | 6 |  |
| Bahrain | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Bangladesh |  | 6 |  |
| Belarus | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Belgium | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Bhutan | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Bolivia |  | 6 |  |
| Bosnia and Herzegovina | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Botswana | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| British Virgin Islands | 6 |  | 6 |
| Brunei | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Cambodia | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Cameroon | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Canada | 6* |  |  |
| Cayman Islands | 6 |  | 6 |
| Central African Republic | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Chad | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| China |  | 6 |  |
| Comoros | 6 |  | 6 |
| Cuba |  | 6 |  |
| Curacao | 6 |  | 6 |
| Czech Republic | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Djibouti |  | 6 |  |
| DR Congo |  | 6 |  |
| Ecuador | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Egypt | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| El Salvador | 6 |  | 6 |
| Equatorial Guinea | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Eritrea |  | 6 |  |
| Estonia | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Eswatini |  | 6 |  |
| Ethiopia |  | 6 |  |
| Fiji | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Finland | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| France | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| French Polynesia |  | 6 |  |
| Gabon | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Germany | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Ghana |  | 6 |  |
| Greece | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Grenada |  | 6 |  |
| Guatemala |  | 6 |  |
| Guinea |  | 6 |  |
| Guinea Bissau | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Guyana | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Haiti |  | 6 |  |
| Honduras | 3 months ARV | 6 |  |
| Iceland | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Indonesia | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Iran | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Iraq | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Israel | 6 |  | 6 |
| Italy | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Ivory Coast | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Jordan | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Kenya | 6 |  | 6 |
| Kiribati | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Kuwait | 3 months DEP | 6 |  |
| Kyrgyzstan |  | 6 |  |
| Laos | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Latvia | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Lebanon | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Liechtenstein | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Lithuania | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Luxembourg | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Madagascar | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Malawi |  | 6 |  |
| Malaysia | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Maldives |  | 6 |  |
| Malta | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Marshall Islands | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Mauritania |  | 6 |  |
| Micronesia | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Moldova | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Monaco | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Mongolia |  | 6 |  |
| Montenegro | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Morocco |  | 6 |  |
| Mozambique |  | 6 |  |
| Myanmar | 6 |  | 6 |
| Namibia | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Nauru | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Nepal |  | 6 |  |
| Netherlands | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| New Caledonia |  | 6 |  |
| New Zealand | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Nicaragua | 6 |  | 6 |
| Nigeria | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| North Korea |  | 6 |  |
| North Macedonia | 3 months ARV |  |  |
| Norway | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Oman | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Pakistan |  | 6 |  |
| Palau | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Panama | 3 months ARV |  |  |
| Papua New Guinea | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Peru |  | 6 |  |
| Philippines | 6 |  | 6 |
| Poland | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Portugal | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Qatar | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Republic of the Congo |  | 6 |  |
| Rwanda | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Saint Lucia | 6 |  | 6 |
| Samoa | 6 |  | 6 |
| Sao Tome and Principe |  | 6 |  |
| Saudi Arabia | 6 |  | 6 |
| Senegal | 3 months ARV | 6 |  |
| Sierra Leone |  | 6 |  |
| Singapore | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Slovakia | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Slovenia | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Solomon Islands | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Somalia | 6 |  | 6 |
| South Sudan |  | 6 |  |
| Spain | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Sri Lanka | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Sudan | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Suriname | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Sweden | 3 months DEP |  |  |
| Taiwan | 6 |  | 6 |
| Tanzania | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Thailand | 6 |  | 6 |
| Timor Leste | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Tokelau | 6 |  | 6 |
| Tonga | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Trinidad and Tobago |  | 6 |  |
| Tunisia |  | 6 |  |
| Turkey |  | 6 |  |
| Turkmenistan |  | 6 |  |
| Tuvalu | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Uganda | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| United Arab Emirates | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Vanuatu | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Venezuela | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Vietnam | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Yemen | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| Zambia |  | 6 |  |
| Zimbabwe | 6 |  | 6 |

> Notes:
>
> - Requirements and conditions may change permanently or temporarily at any time. As such, the listed data should not be considered definitive and travelers should always confirm requirements with official channels at their destination countries.
> - Data pertains to US citizens holding US passports and traveling from the US. Those traveling with passports issued by other countries or traveling from another country of origin may encounter different requirements.
> - Countries marked "3 months ARV" require a visitor's passport to be valid for three months after the visitor's planned arrival date.
> - Countries marked "3 months DEP" require a visitor's passport to be valid for three months after the visitor's planned departure date.

---

I'll add below countries that aren't in this list. Since it sometimes depends on the passport, I'll take the worse case scenario (i.e., the passport requiring the longest validity period), unless specified otherwise:

- Andorra: [3 months](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Andorra.html#:%7E:text=Visit%20Andorra%27s%20Ministry%20of%20Foreign,six%20months%20beyond%20your%20stay.) for US passports.
- USA: 6 months.

Comment: That does not mean that there are no countries with different requirements, there are almost 200 countries in the world.

Comment: @littleadv correct, but that covers ~75% of all countries, which is a decent coverage and more useful than your other comments.

Comment: yeah. But doesn't answer the question. And that's the most important part of an *answer* - answer the question.

Comment: @littleadv some answers can still be useful even if they are incomplete.

Comment: You asked a "yes or no" question, yet your answer is neither. Does any?

Comment: @littleadv no for these 146 surveyed countries.

Comment: Does *any*? That was your question.

Comment: @littleadv I don't know, still searching, but this answer allowed us to go from 0% to 75% coverage. Not bad.

Comment: @littleadv, stop. One comment was enough, more is not needed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, stop, one comment was enough, more is not needed.