# Does the exact passport expiry date in the forms when booking a flight ticket matter assuming that the actual passport expiry date is far away?

Tags: air-travel, passports, bookings

When purchasing a flight ticket online, one sometimes has to indicate the passport expiry date. I don't travel often and I don't know it by heart. I just [know](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185686/1810) that the passport expiry date is far enough in the future that it will please any immigration officer. Is it ok if I just write down some approximate date that is far away in the future or does writing down the exact date matter?

Comment: So .. lying on an immigration form.  Acceptable or not?

Comment: @PeterM no, only when purchasing a flight ticket. I wonder how the airlines or travel agent use that information.

Comment: *Deliberately* entering false information is still lying.  And the premise of the question seems flawed in the first place.  You state that you "*don't travel often*", and as such don't know the expiry date "*by heart*".  But in order to get to that point when buying tickets, you would also have needed to enter your passport *number*.   If you travel so infrequently  that you don't remember the  expiry date, I would posit that you also do not remember your passport number.  Which means that you already need your passport in front of you when making that purchase.

Comment: @PeterM No, I retrieve my passport number from somewhere else.

Comment: If you know only the year, write that. If you know the year and month, write that. But don't *invent* a date to satisfy a computer-required field. Go look it up.

Comment: @WeatherVane "don't invent a date to satisfy a computer-required field": do you mean that the exact passport expiry date in the forms when booking a flight ticket matters?

Comment: As mentioned, if the computer requires you to enter a specific date, don't invent it (don't lie). But if the format is loose, and you enter what you know to be true, you take the risk that someone deems it insufficient information.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Does the exact passport expiry date in the forms when booking a flight ticket matter assuming that the the actual passport expiry date is far away?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt What part of "*don't lie*" isn't clear? The information exists and you have it in your possession.  Unless you get clarification from an airline employee anything we say here is pure speculation.

Comment: @PeterM what part of "does the matter" isn't clear? There are airline employees who use this site, as well as informed travelers.

Comment: Where exactly do you keep your passport? Or conversely, where are you when you make a flight booking? The no-brain answer is to write the passport expiry date in the same place that you wrote its number.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Choosing not to lie removes the need to know if it it matters or not.

Comment: @PeterM I prefer to be informed

Comment: @WeatherVane that's going too far away from the question and the moda are likely to start removing comments. But yes there's a valid explanation to that.

Comment: Is it a required field? Often I find that it is not required at booking, but you must fill the API some time before the flight, so you can fill it later. But I assume it depends on booking site, airline, country

Comment: And: you travel a lot. Get a copy of your passport (the relevant pages) somewhere accessible on Internet. You may need it (e.g. if you forget passport at hotel or in case you lost the passport): it is not an official replacement, but it helps a lot. And it will help in such cases.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Depends on booking site. I don't know if that also depends on the airline and country, but I don't recall any such case. That's partly why I suspect that the passport expiry date indicated on a booking site doesn't matter assuming that the actual passport expiry date is far away.

Answer (score 2):

Never invent information on an offical form that *you* don't think is relevant.

There are several choices for you:

- look up the exact information asked for
- enter less data than asked for that you know to be true, and take the risk that the form will be rejected
- don't complete the form

Comment: There could be a knock-on problem. You enter different dates on various forms, and the organisation that is hoarding them finds a discrepancy later, nearer to when the passport expires.

Comment: Thanks, which organization is hoarding them?

Comment: All of them do, subject to data regulations.

Answer (score 1):

> does writing down the exact date matter?

Probably not, but you can't know for sure, so why risk it ?

It's not entirely clear why some airlines do collect passport info at booking and most do not. Most common seems to be that you can enter passport info optionally and change it anytime between booking and check-in.

The main reason is probably identification and making sure that the booking name matches at least one travel document that you have.

There is absolutely no requirement that the passport used for booking (if required) is the same as the one used for travelling.

Since we don't know exactly why some airlines collect this info and what exactly they do with it, it's certainly the safest option to provide correct information or book with airline that doesn't care.

Comment: " why risk it ?" I value human time.

Comment: That seems disingenuous:  Writing and managing this question here takes you more time than looking up your passport data 20+ times.  I have all my info in a secure online document than I can access on any of my devices anywhere in and pull up any relevant data in a matter seconds. Added benefit: I can copy and past the relevant info, which reduces the risk of typing errors. I suggest spending a few minutes setting that up and than you are all set for any future online forms (whatever they may be)